# Set records dependent on other not yet processed records on hold, until their parents are processed

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a spring batch integration for importing employees in the application. An employee can report to another employee. If the report to employee does not exist it will throw a validation error, which is caught by a SkipListener.

However, the import file is very large and we cannot choose the order of its records, thus an employee can refer to a not yet imported parent.

How can temporary hold the records that fail the previously mentioned validation for a reprocessing (try to import them again)?

I need this such that I can rerun the process just for the records that failed the reports to validation, until their parents have been imported.

Answer (score 1):

There is retry support in spring batch, but I don't think there is deferred retry like I think your looking for.  You could load the data into a staging table as an initial step.  Then have another validation step that reads from staging, finding any staged employees that refer to a non-existent employee and mark them that way in the staging.  A third step could load all the employees that are valid.